# How to remove author name and date created from Simplenews emails?

Tags: emails

When I create a newsletter using the Simplenews module and save it, I don't see the author name and date created in the node. However, when I send email, it contains author name as a **link** and date and time of creation + 'html' as shown.

```
rktaxali Thu, 05/19/2016 - 11:42 html

Unsubscribe from this newsletter
```

Any suggestion, how to remove the author name and date row from email?

On a similar note, the email also includes the node title twice in the body of the email, e.g.

## Quarterly News Letter

Quarterly News Letter

This is sample newsletter sent by the simplenews module ...

Any suggestion, how to remove the two repeating lines at the top of the email?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you two options:

1. You can put node.tpl.php specific to your simplenews content-type and remove the unnecessary content from it.
2. Add css file specific to the mailing system. I use mimemail system, so I did the following:

`function THEME_NAME_preprocess_mimemail_message(&$variables) {
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME').'/css/mail.css');
}`

In the mail.css, you can hide those fields using `display:none;`